# Como pasar datos de una tabla en Razor al Controlador C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

buenos dias o noches compañeros colegas, estoy utilizando una vista donde cargo los datos de un documento en excel con un formulario para que se visualizen en la tabla que tengo en la vista, ahora lo que quiero hacer es que una vez se haya cargado los datos del documento Excel en la tabla  mandarlos a un POST controlador para insertar los datos de la base de datos, hay alguna manera de pasar los datos de la tabla al controlador? Gracias de antemano por su ayuda en esta pregunta

> Aclarando que la carga de datos excel a la tabla funciona correctamente

```html
@model IEnumerable<PesajePrevio>



@{
    ViewBag.Title = "RegistrarPorDocumento";
}

<h2>RegistrarPorDocumento</h2>

@Html.ActionLink("Regresar", "Index", "Pesajes", null, new { @class = "btn btn-outline-primary" })


<form method="post">
    <input type="file" name="file" />
    <button type="submit">Cargar</button>
</form>


<form method="post" action="@Url.Action("InsertarDatos", "Pesajes")">


    <table class="table">
        <thead>

            <tr>

                <th>Fecha</th>

                <th>Boleto</th>

                <th>Hora Entrada</th>

                <th>Hora Salida</th>

                <th>Peso Neto</th>


                <th>Camion</th>

                <th>Placas</th>


                <th>Chofer</th>


            </tr>


        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <tr>


                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FechaEntrada)

                    </td>

                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Boleto)

                    </td>

                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.HoraEntrada)

                    </td>

                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.HoraSalida)

                    </td>

                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Neto)

                    </td>

                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Camion)

                    </td>

                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Placas)

                    </td>

                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Chofer)

                    </td>


                </tr>

            }
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <button type="submit">Enviar datos</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Como tienes el controlador?

Comment: Blazor o razor?

Comment: @gbianchi Razor

Comment: Entonces cambia la etiqueta, porque en blazor no harias esto ;)

Comment: @gbianchi gracias por la ayuda